# How to set Query into variable in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I want to find the item names for the cheapest and most expensive items for each group. But I don't know why I have **SQL error (1064)** near " `SET @maxi := (SELECT A.ItName FROM tblqtdtl B INNER JOIN tblitem A ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode GROUP BY A.ItCode HAVING MAX(B.Price))`". maybe there is something wrong or missing from my sql code

This is what I expecting for

| vd code | vd name | cheapest item | cheapest price | Most expensive item | Most Expensive Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vd001 | DEF Textile | Polyester | 2600 | Polyester | 2600 |
| Vd003 | MNO Textile | Polyester | 3228 | Silk | 3950 |
| Vd004 | XYZ Textile | Polyester | 2800 | Silk | 3480 |

And here's my code

```
SET @mini :=(SELECT A.ItName FROM tblqtdtl B INNER JOIN tblitem A ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode 
                    GROUP BY A.ItCode HAVING MIN(B.Price)
                )
SET @maxi := (SELECT A.ItName FROM tblqtdtl B INNER JOIN tblitem A ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode 
                    GROUP BY A.ItCode HAVING MAX(B.Price)
                 )

SELECT V.VdCode, V.VdName, @mini AS 'Cheapest Item', MIN(B.Price) AS 'Cheapest Price', @maxi AS 'Most Expensive Item'
,MAX(B.Price) AS 'Most Expensive Price'
 
 FROM tblqthdr C 
 INNER JOIN tblvendor V ON C.VdCode = V.VdCode
 INNER JOIN tblqtdtl B ON C.DocNo = B.DocNo
 INNER JOIN tblitem A ON B.ItCode = A.ItCode
 WHERE V.ActInd='Y'
 GROUP BY V.VdCode
```

This is the Input script

tblqdtl

```
INSERT INTO `tblqtdtl` (`DocNo`, `ItCode`, `Price`) VALUES
    ('QT001', 'It004', 38700.00),
    ('QT002', 'It002', 25600.00),
    ('QT003', 'It005', 21000.00),
    ('QT004', 'It004', 34000.00),
    ('QT005', 'It003', 32000.00),
    ('QT006', 'It002', 31780.00),
    ('QT007', 'It001', 28000.00),
    ('QT008', 'It002', 21800.00),
    ('QT009', 'It004', 32600.00),
    ('QT010', 'It002', 27500.00);
```

tblitem

```
INSERT INTO `tblitem` (`ItCode`, `ItName`, `ItCtCode`) VALUES
    ('Itestt001', 'Cotton', 'ALA'),
    ('It002', 'Polyester', 'SIN'),
    ('It003', 'Wool', 'ALA'),
    ('It004', 'Silk', 'ALA'),
    ('It005', 'Rayon', 'SIN');
```

tblqhdr

```
INSERT INTO `tblqthdr` (`DocNo`, `DocDt`, `VdCode`) VALUES
    ('QT001', '20180102', 'Vd003'),
    ('QT002', '20180203', 'Vd001'),
    ('QT003', '20180203', 'Vd002'),
    ('QT004', '20180207', 'Vd004'),
    ('QT005', '20180304', 'Vd003'),
    ('QT006', '20180401', 'Vd003'),
    ('QT007', '20180701', 'Vd005'),
    ('QT008', '20180902', 'Vd002'),
    ('QT009', '20180902', 'Vd005'),
    ('QT010', '20181203', 'Vd004');
```

tblvendor

```
INSERT INTO `tblvendor` (`VdCode`, `VdName`, `ActInd`) VALUES
    ('Vd001', 'ABC Textile', 'Y'),
    ('Vd002', 'DEF Textile', 'N'),
    ('Vd003', 'GHI Textile', 'Y'),
    ('Vd004', 'JKL Textile', 'Y'),
    ('Vd005', 'MNO Textile', 'N');
```

Comment: please share the create table and insert scripts for sample data and output you need.

Comment: sorry for that, I'll share the insert script

Comment: If you provide the error you are getting, it will also help.

Comment: `HAVING MIN(B.Price)` doesn't make any sense. `HAVING` needs to be followed by a true/false condition expression. Do you mean `HAVING B.Price = MIN(B.Price)`?

Comment: But when you use a subquery as an expression to assign to a variable, it has to return just one value. If there are multiple items with the minimum price, your assignment will try to assign them all to the `@mini` variable, which isn't possible.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried that, but still have the same error

Comment: Someone already asked you to add the error message to the question.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for that, I just added it to the question

Comment: Replace `HAVING MIN(B.Price)` with `ORDER BY MIN(B.Price) ASC LIMIT 1` (and so on). And use not `SET @var := (subquery)` but `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: You're missing the `;` at the end of each query.

Comment: *This is what I expecting for* Price values in desired output does not match ones in sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       VdCode,
       VdName,
       FIRST_VALUE(ItName) OVER (PARTITION BY VdCode ORDER BY Price ASC) `Cheapest item`,
       MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY VdCode) `Cheapest price`,
       FIRST_VALUE(ItName) OVER (PARTITION BY VdCode ORDER BY Price DESC) `Most expensive item`,
       MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY VdCode) `Most Expensive Price`
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM tblqthdr C 
       INNER JOIN tblvendor V USING (VdCode)
       INNER JOIN tblqtdtl B USING (DocNo)
       INNER JOIN tblitem A USING (ItCode)
       WHERE V.ActInd='Y' ) subquery
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53cade7afe509dcde6f259e5c5ae3fa3